# ¿Cómo dar formato a las fechas en un cardView en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date

Diferentes fechas almacenadas en Millis en una base de datos (SQLite) para ser mostradas en un cardView. Puedo ver las fechas en Millis, pero al aplicar `DateFormat` me muestra todas las fechas con la misma fecha.

Con este código se muestra la fecha en Millis:

```
viewHolder.dateView.setText(cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex));
```

Y con éste lo muestra en formato fecha, pero la fecha no es la correcta y es la misma en todos los cardView (31/12/1969):

```
viewHolder.dateView.setText(DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", dateColumnIndex));
```

`dateColumnIndex` es la fecha en Millis almacenada en la base de datos.

```
public class EntrevistaListAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EntrevistaListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Cursor cursor;
int entrevistaColumnIndex;
//long dateColumnIndex;
int dateColumnIndex;
int idColumnIndex;


public void swapCursor(Cursor c) {
    cursor = c;
    if(c!=null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        entrevistaColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(EntrevistaProvider.COLUMN_ENTREVISTA);
        dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(EntrevistaProvider.COLUMN_DATE_TIME);
        idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(EntrevistaProvider.COLUMN_ENTREVISTAID);

    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_entrevista, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final long id = getItemId(i);
    final Context context = viewHolder.entrevistaView.getContext();

    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
    viewHolder.entrevistaView.setText(cursor.getString(entrevistaColumnIndex));

    //this code shows wrong format date: 31/12/1969 in all cards.
    viewHolder.dateView.setText(DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", dateColumnIndex));
    viewHolder.dateView2.setText(DateFormat.format("k:mm", dateColumnIndex));
    viewHolder.dateView3.setText(DateFormat.format("EEEE", dateColumnIndex));


    //this code shows the date and time in Millis correctly:
    //viewHolder.dateView.setText(cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex));


    //and this one shows a mess: the time in Millis and date format (31/00/1969 ALWAYS)
    //viewHolder.dateView.setText(cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex)
    // + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd/mm/yyyy",dateColumnIndex));

    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((OnEditEntrevista) context).editEntrevista(id);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener( new View
            .OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle(R.string.delete_q)
                    .setMessage(viewHolder.entrevistaView.getText())
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,null)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.delete,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface
                                                            dialogInterface,
                                                    int i) {
                                    deleteEntrevista(context,id);
                                }
                            })
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void deleteEntrevista(Context context, long entrevistaId) {
    context.getContentResolver()
            .delete(
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            EntrevistaProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                            entrevistaId),
                    null, null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    return cursor.getLong(idColumnIndex);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cursor!=null ? cursor.getCount() : 0;
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView entrevistaView;
    TextView dateView,dateView2,dateView3;

    public ViewHolder(CardView itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = itemView;
        entrevistaView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text5);
        dateView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        dateView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        dateView3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);

    }

}
```

}

[image: las capturas]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tipo de `dateColumnIndex`?

Comment: es int, también he probado con long y da lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el problema es que le estás pasando un `int` a `DateFormat.format`. Según la [documentación de android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html), parece que el método `format` toma como parámetro una variable de tipo `Date` y no un entero.

Prueba a crear una `Date` a partir del entero y después le das el formato que quieras con `DateFormat` o `SimpleDateFormat`, algo como esto (ojo, no lo he probado y puede que falle):

```
Date aux = new Date(dateColumnIndex);
viewHolder.dateView.setText(DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", aux));
```

Comment: Al parecer la mejor forma es con `DateFormat`  seleccionando `(android.text.format)` NO `(java.text)` y de `format` seleccionando `(CharqSecuence inFormat, long inTimeinMillis)` o sea el formato que quiero ("dd/MM/yyyy") y la variable que esta en millis (dateColumnIndex)

Comment: no funcionó la de `Date aux = new Date(dateColumnIndex);`

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir el tu fecha en millisegundos, existen varias opciones, por ejemplo si tienes un valor
1471288531473
La conversión es:
15/08/16 19:15

Hay varias opciones, puedes usar la clase Calendar para obtener año, mes y día:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);

    int mAnio = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Puedes concatenar los valores con el caracter "/" y crear tu formato deseado.

Otro metodo obteniendo el formato corto:

```
long millis = 1471288531473;

 String miFecha = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(millis);
```

Comment: tengo entendido que no es necesario usar calendar, pues la fecha ya esta, en Millis, solo hay que darle formato. Aun no lo logro con la segunda opción `getDateInstance`.Gracias

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta correcta es ( ya verificada): hay que instanciar el Calendar en  onBindViewHolder ademas de obtener en Long la fecha almacenada en integer en SQlite y ya en el holder darle formato:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(EntrevistaProviderCOLUMN_DATE_TIME)));
viewHolder.dateView.setText(newSimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy).format(calendar.getTime()));
```